# Reference to newly copied checkbox in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I copy a column from another column in a worksheet (side-by-side).
As there's a checkbox in the column, it's copied as well - as intended. But strangely enough, it's getting the same name as its original. How do I get the reference of this newly created checkbox?

Some 'simplyfied' code in sheet module to illustrate:

```
Dim cell as Range
Set cell = cells(1,2) 
Columns(cell.Usedrange.Column).Copy
cell.EntireColumn.Insert
```

I manage somehow to get hold of the reference by looping through each Checkbox object choosing the FIRST occurrence of the original name (I've experimented to get to this result):

```
Dim oCB as Checkbox
For Each oCB In .CheckBoxes
    If oCB.Name = "nameOfOriginalCheckbox" Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next oCB
```

But it is not satisfying as there are two 'objects' with the same name (?), as it's not bulletproof. I've as well tried to use the TopLeftCell-property, but both checkboxes are also attached to the same cell ...

The structure of the code is not possible to change, so I only need suggestions as how to get hold of this reference of this new created Checkbox.

> **EDIT**

I've delved more into it: when the dublicates (clones) are made (script running) they are strictly the same in the Shapesobject: they get same IDs, same left position etc.
I've tried to call the three Application.CalculateFull,CalculateFullRebuild and CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone and a DoEvents in my script, just after the clone has been created, but it does neither update the objects: they have the exact properties. Until the script has finished:
Because if I run through the Shapes objects, when the script has finished, they've all gotten their own IDs etc...
It look like as if Excel is doing its tidying up - after an COPY/INSERT - when a 'user'-script has ended ...

Comment: If you `Debug.Print oCB.Name` of all the checkboxes on the worksheet there are two of them with the same name? I tried your code and I'm getting `Check Box 1` and `Check Box 2`

Comment: @PeterT. I've tried what you propose. It's from here I discovered the doubled name. I rename each of the Checkboxes programmically. Maybe it's therefore they get the same name? But after having had a short break from the computer, I thought that the solutions could be using one of the ofter properties of checkboxes ...